# How do I convert an observable that emits an array into an observable that emits each value of the array individually?

Tags: arrays, rxjs, observable, rxfire

I'm using RXFire and RXJS.

```
collectionData(firebase.firestore.collection('collectionname')).subscribe(x=>console.log(x)
```

returns

```
// [{document1}, {document2}]
```

What i'd like is an observable that returns

```
// {document1}
// {document2}
```

I've tried using a combination of from() and toArray() (i.e. converting the observable to a plain array and back to an observable that emits each document one by one) but toArray() only creates an observable that emits an array, not an actual array. I need an operation thats the OPPOSITE of toArray(). Take an observable that emits an array and turn it into an observable that emits each value individually.

How do I do that?

---

Edit:

I also tried doing something like

```
const newObs = oldObs.subscribe(x => from(x))
```

but that store the subscriber, not the new observable. =(

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are multiple ways to do that. For example:

```
collectionData(firebase.firestore.collection('collectionname'))
  .pipe(
    concatAll(),
  )
  .subscribe();
```

You can also use `concatMap(array => array)`.

Instead of `concat*` you can use `merge*` as well.